# How to Draw erd and logical diagram?

Tags: sql, database, erd

One of the latest projects is to organise an outdoor summer music festival known as the ‘Long-Weekend’ over a three-day period, and they really need a system to help them record and access the data. It is hoped that the festival will attract between 4000 and 5000 fans each day during the three-day period. Recently they had an event of folk music festival in Roundhay Park, Leeds. They haven’t got much social media presence, therefore, they would like to include links to relevant social media as part of your final product. The system needs to be accessible to multiple users.

In addition to above, here is a list of some other important information we need to include in the system:

1. Details for each Festival and the key organizer of the Festival.

   - Details of Venues and Locations where the festival is taking place, and Contact person for the Venue
   - Details of Venue as they may be of a different types/sizes and hire price.
   - List of all staff working at the Festival
   - List of Bands playing at Festival.
   - Additional Entertainment to keep fans occupied over a period
   - The music bands represented by an agent need to play a prominent Venue
   - Space for band/singers should be allocated for storage
   - A list of bands on each location, times and dates are kept
   - Allocation of staff to a stage and supervisor and the ability to record feedback
   - Reporting on the equipment list for each stage
   - Security staff allocated to a venue and each stage (if applicable)
   - Information of qualified first aiders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this forum is purely related to code stuff while you have asked some conceptual to logical conversion.

Anyway, I will try to answer:

- Identify the entities like bands, venues, staff etc
- Identify their attributes like bandId, bandTitle or venueTitle, venueAddress, venueContactPerson
- Identify the strong/week/multiple/composite attributes of these entities for example title of band will be single, address can be composite by combination of streetAddress, streetNo, sector, city etc, contactPerson can be multiple
- Identify the relations between entities for example band has many staff member, a member can not be part of multiple bands etc

  - Try to Draw diagram by following https://www.smartdraw.com/entity-relationship-diagram/

Further, you can email me at ping@naveedramzan.com